# В каких областях больше применяется C#, а в каких Java ? Помогите определиться с выбором

Tags: java, c#

В каких областях больше применяется C#, а в каких Java ?

Оба энтерпрайз, оба мобильные приложения: Android, WP7  (Mango).

Стою перед выбором что в свободное время изучать. В будущем клепать формочки (и прописывать к ним события - утрируя конечно же) нет желания... Хочется чего-то интересного? что выбрать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

на мой взгляд статья на википедии многое грамотно описывает: [Сравнение C Sharp и Java](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_C_Sharp_и_Java)

лично я работаю с C# особенно мне нравится фреймворк ASP.NET MVC, на нём и фокусируюсь, хотя работал и с WinForms, WPF/Silverlight(не профессионально)

Comment: а ещё что умеете?

Answer (score 7):

В зависимости от задачи, например C# часто используется в среде с БД MS SQL, Java - Oracle.   Хороший разработчик выбирает язык под задачу, а не приспосабливает определенный язык под все задачи.

Comment: Правильный ответ. Настоящий программист, для специфической задачи - разберется с необходимым языком. Но не станет городить тонны кода на том языке, который знает!

Answer (score 3):

В свое время знание C# сильно облегчило изучение Java, есть много похожего с точки зрения синтаксиса. ИМХО, лучше начинать с C#, так как он более читабельный и понятный.

Comment: да и среда разработки - Visual Studio - проще

Answer (score 3):

Для мобильных приложений джава используется чаще шарпа.

Для кросплатформенной разработки Windows/Linux - тоже джава. Хотя, вероятно, это со временем изменится. Код компилятора открыт, код самого .net'а - тоже.

Для десктопных приложений джава под вопросом. Фреймвёки есть, тот же Open Office доказывает, что сделать на ней что-то десктопное хорошо можно. Но всё же таких примеров очень мало.

И то и другое достаточно популярно для web-разработки. Собсвенно, она сейчас весьма востребована.

Если выберешь джаву, то будешь разгребать кучу xml'я - он там почти во все фреймвёки понапихан. Плюс, никакого синтксического сахара, никакой перегрузки операторов, никаких свойств, всё жутко громоздкое и с длинными именами.

Если C#, то там всё делается для удобства программиста. Перегрузка операторов есть свойства есть, делегаты (по сути, указатели на функции) есть. Постоянно рассматриваются новые фичи, язык активно развивается, хотя в самой платформе .net изменений происходит крайне мало.

Ну и ещё, моё личное мнение: просто так запустить что-то, написанное на джаве, с первого раза почти никогда не получается. Надо полазить по переменным среды, убедиться в номере версии установленной джавы и так далее... Своеобразный linux-way. А на шарпе всё как-то работает сразу. Фреймвёрк обычно уже установлен, но даже если нет, то его надо просто поставить и всё заработает. Никакой дополнительной возни.